# Run JS after div contents loaded from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

There are a ton of proposed answers to my question, but even with all the answers I have found, I can not seem to get any to work. I can make the **JS** work by adding a delay in execution of the code, but I can't rely on a delay to execute the **JS** after div has finished loading it's **HTML**.

I'm creating a page where users can search for an item, and the results are displayed in a `div` using `AJAX`. I need some **JS** to run after the div's html has finished loading. Some of the results data will be hidden until a user clicks on it. The **JS** code to accomplish this is what I am trying to run once the div finishes loading.

I have tried the following extensively with no luck anywhere:

- `.load`
- `.ajaxComplete`
- `.complete`
- `.success`
- `.done`
- `Document.ready`
- I'm sure there are a few others as well, but my brain is just too beat up from dealing with this to remember everything I've tried so far.

My HTML:

```
<form name ="CardName" method="post" action="">
<div "class="w2ui-field">
<div> <input type="list" Name="CardName" id="CardName" style="width: 80%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="w2ui-buttons">
<input type="submit" name="search" style="clear: both; width:80%" value="Search" class="btn">
</div>
</form>
<div class="Results" id="Results" name="Results"></div>
```

My JS:

```
  $(function() {
    $("#CardSearch").bind('submit',function() {
      var value = $('#CardName').val();
        $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "synergies.php",
           data: {value}
        })
        .success(function(data) {
         $("#Results").html(data);
        })
        .complete(function() {
         alert("div updated!"); //Trying to run JS code AFTER div finishes loading
        });
       return false;
    });
  });
```

If there is anything else that could help with this request just let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest to append your JS code between <script></script> tags at the bottom of the php file that handles the AJAX request. This might be almost considered a hack by some, but in some situations (e.g. GoogleMaps implementation) it works best. Good luck!

Comment: You aren't binding submit event to the FORM regarding your posted HTML markup

Comment: Tried adding `<script></script>` tags at the bottom of the PHP file. As far as I have read. JS does not execute when brought in through AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `success` and `failure` are options that you should provide to the `$.ajax` call, not the returned promise. Also, `bind` is deprecated in favour of `on` since jQuery 1.7. Finally, you need to give the value that you're posting to your PHP page a key so that it can be retrieved via `$_POST`. Try this:

```
$("#CardSearch").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "synergies.php",
        data: {
            CardName: $('#CardName').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#Results").html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            alert("div updated!"); //Trying to run JS code AFTER div finishes loading
        }
    })
});
```

You can then retrieve the value sent in your `synergies.php` file using `$_POST['CardName']`.

If you prefer to use the method provided by the returned promise, you can do that like the below, although the result is identical.

```
$("#CardSearch").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "synergies.php",
        data: {
            CardName: $('#CardName').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#Results").html(data);
    }).always(function() {
        alert("div updated!"); 
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried using both of these solutions, and they actually both moved me backwards in terms of things working. I updated my synergies.php file from `$searchResult = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value']);`
to
`$searchResult = htmlspecialchars($_POST['CardName']);`
but with your code, I can't even get the results to show up in the div. The page just refreshes, and does nothing.

Comment: Check the selector for the form is correct - in the HTML it should be `CardName`, yet in your JS it was `CardSearch`. Also, check for errors in the console elsewhere in your code that may be affecting it.

Comment: Still no luck. I checked the selector and made sure the HTML matched the JS. I may just go back to just having the page refresh as I've been tinkering with this for a few days now, and its just leaving me tilted. I put my old JS back in, and the div updates without page refresh. Update the JS with suggested code changes, and the page goes back to refreshing, and not updating the div.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? Press F12 in your browser to see it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try **Synchronous Ajax request**, demo code is given below:

```
$(function() {
   $("#CardSearch").bind('submit',function() {
       e.preventDefault();
       sendData = $('#CardName').val();
       reqUrl =  "synergies.php";
       // this will wait until server request complete 
       var ajaxOpt = AjaxSyncRequest(reqUrl, sendData);
       // after complete server request
       ajaxOpt.done(function(data) { 
           $("#Results").html(data); 
       });
   });
});  

function AjaxSyncRequest(reqUrl, sendData) {
     var ajaxData = $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: reqUrl,
           data: {
              data: sendData
           }
      });
    return ajaxData;
 }
```

Comment: Just FYI - that's not synchronous, but that's a good thing as making synchronous requests is *incredibly* bad practice.

Comment: Tried using your suggestion as well. This suggestion also takes me back a few steps. When I try using this code, my page goes back to refreshing (Trying to avoid this), and the data does not get added to the div.